# Two touches in touchesBegan in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two touches in method "touchesBegan" they both starts at the same time, but i want to second touch to wait while first touch end. How can i achieve that? Here are what I have:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location =[touch locationInView:self.view];
        SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

     if(touchedNode && [touchedNode.name isEqual:@"tapButton"]){
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"buttons.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]]; 
            [self createBackLn];
            [self createBottom];
            [self ballCreate];
            [tapButton removeFromParent];

        }
    if (groupSprite.children.count < 3) {

        CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchlocation.x, IS_IPAD()?108: 75);

        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board"];
        if(IS_IPAD()){
            sprite.xScale = 0.5;
            sprite.yScale = 0.7;
        }else{
            sprite.xScale = 0.3;
            sprite.yScale = 0.5;
        }

        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.zPosition = 2;
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boardCategory;
        sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory | secballCategory;

        SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:IS_IPAD()?0.6:0.4];
        SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,remove]];
        [sprite runAction:actionSequence];
        [groupSprite addChild:sprite];
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: May be you need just `UITapGestureRecognizer `? `numberOfTapsRequired = 2`?

Comment: Can you pls be more specific ? What do you mean by two touches ? you mean double tap or two finger touch at same time ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri what i mean is, when I tap on "tapButton"  sprite node shows up at the same time, I want to  sprite node to start only after "tapButton" is presed

Comment: you have the ability to do `ELSE IF` ,  so you check `if(button) else if(sprite)`